# $f\in L^1(\mu)$, simple measurable functions $s_n(x) \nearrow |f(x)|$ as $n\to \infty$. Can we use Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Given $f\in L^1(\mu)$, we can have a sequence of simple measurable functions $s_n(x) \nearrow |f(x)|$ as $n\to \infty$ for every $x\in X$. Can we use Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Can $|f(x)|$ be unbounded? If it can, how can we use LMCT to show that $$\int_Xs_nd\mu \to \int_Xfd\mu \text{ as } n \to \infty$$.

Comment: Can the MCT allow unbounded functions?

Comment: @SeanNemetz I think it doesn't allow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: If you look at the Lebesgue MCT section of the article it looks like it can apply unbounded functions

Comment: Depends if you allow equality at infinity. If so, then Beppo Levi holds since $s_n$ is integrable.

Comment: Look at Remark 1 in "Monotone convergence theorem for Lebesgue integral" of your posted article

Answer (score 0):

> Can |f(x)| be unbounded?

Yes that is absolutely allowed in any cases. (If your question is, if any $L^1$-function can be unbounded generally, consider the measure space $((0,1), \mathcal{B}((0,1)), \lambda)$ where $\mathcal{B}((0,1))$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra and $\lambda$ the corresponding Lebesgue-measure. Then $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ is unbounded and $L^1$-integrable.)

Most, if not all modern authors even use the [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\mathbb{R} \cup \lbrace{-\infty, \infty}\rbrace$ with some special rules and restrictions, where functions my also have the value $\infty$. Even in that case the MCT is true.

> Can we use Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem?

No, there is something that you missed in your statement. The functions $s_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ need to be greater or equal $0$. As a counterexample, consider $([0, \infty), \mathcal{B}([0,\infty), \lambda))$, $f \equiv 0$ and $s_n = -\chi_{[n-1, \infty)}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: Unfortunately those $s_n$s are not $L^1$ !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1647109 actually states it should be true!

Comment: His question stated that the $s_n$ are simple measurable functions which they are. The second paragraph of that answer you posted states "if ∫fk is allowed to be −∞, the result can be false." is exactly the case in my example.

Comment: You are right, it was not stated in the question, that those functions are $L^1$, only $f$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated clearly. By the theorem on my textbook, there exists $0\leq s_1(x) \leq s_1(x) \leq \cdots \leq f$ if $f: X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable. Theorem 1.17 on Rudin's real and complex analysis.

Comment: Can we say that? The function $|f|$ can be unbounded. If it's unbounded, then $|f|=+\infty$, and hence $0\leq s_1(x) \leq s_1(x) \leq \cdots \leq |f| =+\infty$ for every $x\in X$. If $|f|$ is bounded, then it is true that $0\leq s_1(x) \leq s_1(x) \leq \cdots \leq |f| \leq +\infty$ for every $x\in X$. Therefore, we can use LMCT.