# Wrong formulation of Monotone Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

In my Probability Theory Lecture we stated the Theorem of *Monotone Convergence*:

> Let $Y, Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be discrete, integrable, real-valued random variables with $Y_k \uparrow Y$ almost surely , e.g. $Y_1 \leq Y_2 \leq \dots$ a.s and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } Y_k = Y$ a.s. Then we have:
>
> $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[Y_k] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$$

And I'm wondering if this formulation is correct, since I can't find the non-negativity of the $Y_i's$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you do also need nonnegativity, see here. https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/mynotes.pdf                      Page 5

Comment: @djkat Do you have a counter example with negative random variables? I can't find one in the linked paper.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647106/why-is-the-monotone-convergence-theorem-restricted-to-a-nonnegative-function-seq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. Note that $Y_k-Y_1\uparrow Y-Y_1$ a.s. and $Y_k-Y_1\geq 0$ a.s. Applying monotone convergence we get $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbb E[Y_k-Y_1]=\mathbb E[Y-Y_1]. $$Finally use the integrabilities of $Y_k$s and $Y$ to obtain $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbb E[Y_k]=\mathbb E[Y].$$

Comment: Thank you! So often the monotone convergence is stated with non-negativity as an requirement, but it's easy to prove the result without the restriction starting from there.

Comment: Can you provide details for the last steps, I.e, going from $E[Y_k-Y_1]$ etc to $E[Y_k]$?  Also this result is a corollary of the standard Monotone Convergence theorem,  you used it crucially in your proof.

Comment: @djkat I think we need to require $\mathbb{E}[Y_1] < \infty$ as well. Then the proof above works just fine.

Comment: @user7802048 I think you need more, at least that $E[Y] < \infty$ so you can use bounded convergence - i believe you need to use some sort of convergence theorem here.

Comment: @djkat I don't think $\mathbb{E}[Y] < \infty$ is required. We can use the monotone convergence theorem with non-negativity to prove this version of the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @user7802048 ok I mis-interpreted your earlier comment :)

Comment: @djkat The integrabilities allow us to write $\mathbb E[Y_k-Y_1]$ as $\mathbb E[Y_k]-\mathbb E[Y_1]$ and finally to cancel $\mathbb E[Y_1]$ in the identity $\lim\mathbb E[Y_k]-\mathbb E[Y_1]=\mathbb E[Y]-\mathbb E[Y_1]$.

Comment: I dont mean to belabor the point, but do you have a reference for this fact? I can't shake my analyst background and worry about the triangle inequality /absolute value in E[Y_k - Y_1] etc?

Comment: @djkat I don't see what absolute values you're worried about. $[\cdot]\ne|\cdot|$. (Would maybe have been better to use $(\cdot)$, so it doesn't look like an absolute value...)